# Internal redirect from page to category

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect, template-redirect

I want to implement a page, let's say `/today-deals` that will show all posts under today category, like if we were navigating to `/category/deals-for-october-31-2018` but without changing the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved it using `template_include` hook:

```
add_filter(
    'template_include',
    function ($template) {
       if (is_page('today-deals')) {
                global $wp_query;
                $wp_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => date('Ymd') ) );
                $template = 'category.php';
        }


        return $template;
    }
);
```